# Conditional header in react-native StackNavigator

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to control whether or not my StackNavigator header appears via `this.props.navigation.state.params`.

I have a screen with the following navigationOptions:

```
static navigationOptions = ( {navigation} ) => ({
    header: navigation.state.params.headerConfig,
});
```

and I navigate to the screen as follows:

```
<Button
      onPress={() => navigate('MyScreen', { headerConfig: _____} ) }
      title="Continue"
/>
```

, where ____ is what I am unsure about. If I put `null` then the header disappears, but what can I put there if I don't want the header to disappear?

I tried entering `HeaderProps` instead of ____.

Any help or alternative approaches would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want it do disappear then don't set it to null, leave it undefined and you will get the default one.

```
static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    if (navigation.state.params.hideHeader) {
        return {header: null}
    }
    return {title: 'Home'}
}
```